# Varnish proxy to other domain without generating 302's

Tags: proxy, cross-domain, varnish

Heey all,

I'm wondering if I can proxy traffic with some specific url to a different domain with Varnish!

For example: 
http://myfirstdomain/some/path/hello should get the response from http://myseconddomain.com/hello

I don't want to redirect the browser so varnish should do this. This is a really important requirement for me.

Is this possible? and if so then how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You simple need to rewrite contents of `req.http.host` and/or `req.url` during `vcl_recv`.

Comment: Thnx, I was initially already so close :) I will paste the my configuration this afternoon but it was as simple as you described.